# how to apply findstr expressions to the first column of a string in a .csv file while returning the entire string in CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I made a btach script and which works well, with the exception of returning additional strings that are not exact matches to the source file.

When i run the script below, it will return additional strings that share the same number structure as the the numbers in the `.txt` file, but with additional numbers at the end of them ex.

searching for `"^%%L"` which = `"^12210"` will return strings for 12210 and 122100,122101,122102 ect..

Any help is greatly appreciated!

batch script:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    for /f %%f in ("%%a"\*.txt) do (
        for /f %%L in (%%f) do (
            findstr "^%%L" C:path\file.csv  >> %%a.csv
        ) 
    )
    move %%a.csv "%%a" >nul
)
```

Comment: If you edit the question and paste in a few example records it would be helpful.

Comment: You got it, updating it now, thanks

Comment: If the csv has a comma as delimiter include it in the findstr `findstr "^%%L,"`

Comment: @LotPings-Thanks for the comment! If i add the comma it would still return strings with additional characters between the end of `^%%L` and the comma. ^1001, would also return strings for ^10010, ^10011, etc. Is there is a way to use `^%%L$` and `findstr` based off of the first column in a string and still have it return the entire string? instead of $ marking the end of a string, have it mark the end of a partial string?

Comment: I didn't read your entire question. You included a lot of points that are not related to the problem. You should learn to post much more concise questions. You should describe your problem in 4-5 lines, post the input data, post your code, post the current result and a brief description of the desired result. When your description is verbose and ample the people lost interest in reading it. At least, that happen to me because I have not enough spare time right now to read your large description. Perhaps if you cut down your description I could read it, but I am not entirely sure right now...

Comment: `FindStr`s **`^`** and **`$`** are for beginning and end of line respectively, I'm therefore assuming that the data you require would be available by matching beginning or end of words using **`\<`** and **`\>`**. You can do that using either `FindStr "\<12210,\>" "C:\path\file.csv"` or `FindStr "\<12210\>" "C:\path\file.csv"`. Alternatively you can use `Find` like this, `Find "12210,"<"C:\path\file.csv"`.

Comment: You can also use a mixture of beginning of line with end of word for more robustness: `FindStr/B "12210,\>" "C:\path\file.csv"` or  `FindStr "^12210,\>" "C:\path\file.csv"`.

Comment: @Compo- Thanks for the assist!! Your comments got me going in the right direction and the problem is solved. I ended up having to modify the expression a bit to return the entire string. Here is what worked. `findstr "^%%L,*,*\>" C:\path\file.csv.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Compo- Thanks for the assist!! Your comments got me going in the right direction and the problem is solved. I ended up having to modify the expression a bit to return the entire string. Here is what worked.

```
findstr "^%%L,*,*\>" C:\path\file.csv.
```